# Quick Regex Python 3 not working

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, tuples

```
if re.findall(r"i am .*", a):
    reg = re.compile(r" i am ([\w]+).*?$")
    print('How long have you been {}?'.format(*reg.findall(a)))
```

So if i input:

```
i am struggling with life...
```

it should output:

```
How long have you been struggling?
```

But for some reason i get a tuple error?

By the way a is just an input field.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 14, in <module>
    print('How long have you been {}?'.format(*reg.findall(a)))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second regular expression doesn't match:

```
re.compile(r" i am ([\w]+).*?$")
```

because it starts with a space. Remove that initial space and it works fine:

```
>>> a = 'i am struggling with life...'
>>> reg = re.compile(r" i am ([\w]+).*?$")
>>> reg.findall(a)
[]
>>> reg = re.compile(r"i am ([\w]+).*?$")
>>> reg.findall(a)
['struggling']
```

The exception you see is thrown because the `.format()` method receives positional arguments as a tuple, tries to look up item 0 and as it was passed an *empty* set of arguments you get the `IndexError`.

Comment: One more thing... @Martijn Pieters how do i get strings like Pi am to not show up? Like i want Pi am not to register.

Comment: Anchor the regular expression to the start of the string with `^` or `\A`, or use `re.match()` to only look at the start of a string.

Comment: Okay thanks @Martjin Pieters, but i don't mean the start of a string. like it could be something like: You annoy me so i am frustrated. And i want it to return Frustrated. Could i do an either statement? i think something like: [^| ]

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer: Use `\b` to anchor to word boundaries instead then.